# Where can I find the pdb source code?

Tags: python, debugging, python-3.x, pdb

I would like to modify the source code of Python 3.4's built in debugger, `pdb` (I'm assuming it's written in Python). I would like to add some code so that when I put:

```
pdb.set_trace(locals())
```

in my code, it invokes the standard `pdb` interface in the console, and also automatically displays formatted information about my local environment variables similar to the table below.

Can someone point me to the source code for `pdb`?

```
-------------------- Objects: -----------------------------------[2000]
[Name: dog]     [Data type: "Dog"]          [2100]
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
|  ID  | breed | color |  name |    size    |    uuid    |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 2110 |  lynx | black | dog-3 | large!!!!! | e30475ad-9 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
[Name: cat]     [Data type: "Cat"]          [2200]
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
|  ID  | breed | color |   name  |    size    |
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
| 2210 |  lynx | black | kitty-5 | large!!!!! |
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+

-------------------- Lists of Objects: --------------------------[3000]
[Name: cats]     [Data type: "list"]          [3100]
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
|  ID  | breed | color |   name  |    size    |
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
| 3110 |  lynx | black | kitty-1 | large!!!!! |
| 3120 |  lynx | black | kitty-2 | large!!!!! |
| 3130 |  lynx | black | kitty-3 | large!!!!! |
| 3140 |  lynx | black | kitty-4 | large!!!!! |
| 3150 |  lynx | black | kitty-5 | large!!!!! |
+------+-------+-------+---------+------------+
[Name: dogs]     [Data type: "list"]          [3200]
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
|  ID  | breed | color |  name |    size    |    uuid    |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
| 3210 |  lynx | black | dog-1 | large!!!!! | e30475ad-9 |
| 3220 |  lynx | black | dog-2 | large!!!!! | e30475ad-9 |
| 3230 |  lynx | black | dog-3 | large!!!!! | e30475ad-9 |
+------+-------+-------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: You know there's a link to the **Source code:** right at the top of [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), right? It takes you to the online Mercurial repository: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/pdb.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) is just a normal module that’s shipped as part of the standard library. As such, you can just look into your local `lib` folder to find the `pdb.py` source.

Of course, you can also look at it online, e.g. on the [Python source repository](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/pdb.py).